# Failure while running SQLCMD with -E option for a AD user

Tags: sql-server, sqlcmd

I am trying to run SQLCMD with E option as shown below,

```
sqlcmd -E -S <MY_SQL_SERVER> -Q "<some script>".
```

However, it fails with an below error,

> "Login failed for user '<Domain_name><user_name>'. Reason: Could not find a login matching the name provided."

The SQL server uses windows authentication and has a login setup. This login is then mapped with a windows user group. This AD user is a part of the windows user group.

Any idea why such problem can come? and how to resolve this?

Comment: The error very strongly suggests that you do not have a login on the server for the AD Login on the instance you are connecting to. Perhaps you aren't running the script under the credentials you think you are, or otherwise the account really doesn't have a login.

Comment: Is it possible to check if that specific AD user has a login or not by running script?

Comment: You can check `sys.principles` to see if it's listed in there. If it connects via an AD group, you'd need to check if any of the groups it is a member of is in there.

Comment: @Larnu Problem is running any query, even while querying sys.server_principals or sys.sql_logins from SQLCMD with -E option fails with the error mentioned above (for the AD user). Do we need to run these query with local system administrator to see login details as AD user does not seem to be having rights to run these queries.

Comment: Is this a new instance? If so, then use the login into the server as whomever you gave `sysadmin` to. Otherwise use the `sa` account to make the initial logins.